# How to show a div at the very bottom of a menu

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="glb-nav glb-nav-vertical glb-nav-left">
    <div class="glb-nav-top">
        <div class="glb-nav-logo">Example</div>
        <div class="glb-nav-left-arrow"></div>
        <div class="glb-nav-apps">
        </div>
        <div class="glb-nav-links">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="glb-nav-profile">
        <div class="glb-nav-profile-image"><img src="/images/Profile.svg" /></div>
        <div class="glb-nav-profile-name"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="glb-nav-social-icons">
        <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-tw"></div>
        <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-fb"></div>
        <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-in"></div>
        <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-lk"></div>
        <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-pi"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It forms a menu. I need the `glb-nav-social-icons` and the `glb-nav-profile` to show up at the bottom of the menu at all times, regardless of whether we resize the page. How can I get that done?

I was thinking of adding the following css to `glb-nav-top`:

```
.glb-nav-top {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-height: calc(100vh - 185px);
}
```

But in Firefox, the social icons and profile doesn't show at the very bottom (there is some spacing at the bottom).

Note that glb-nav has a `position: fixed`

Also note that when the window gets smaller in height, I don't want the bottom to every overlap with the top. The bottom should move upward until it reaches the bottom of the top (glb-nav-top) div.

Comment: You could also use flex, it makes this very easy

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using a wrapper around those two elements and setting `position: absolute`, `bottom: 0`, and `left: 0` on it to position them at the bottom of your menu regardless of what happens to the rest of your page.

In this example, I wrapped the two elements that you want to push down to the bottom in a `div` with the class `abs`. Then I absolutely positioned that div at the bottom of its containing div.

**Live Demo:**

```css
.glb-nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: blue;
  height: 200px;
}

.glb-nav-profile {
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
}

.glb-nav-social-icons {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
}

.abs {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="glb-nav glb-nav-vertical glb-nav-left">
  <div class="glb-nav-top">
    <div class="glb-nav-logo">Example</div>
    <div class="glb-nav-left-arrow"></div>
    <div class="glb-nav-apps">
    </div>
    <div class="glb-nav-links">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="abs">

    <div class="glb-nav-profile">
      <div class="glb-nav-profile-image"><img src="/images/Profile.svg" /></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-profile-name"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="glb-nav-social-icons">
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-tw"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-fb"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-in"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-lk"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-pi"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/6n1cw8tz/

Comment: the problem is glb-nav has a position: fixed

Comment: @PotaOnasys The absolute positioning will work as long as `glb-nav` has any position other than `static`.

Comment: @PotaOnasys I've updated my answer to use `position: fixed` on `glb-nav`.

Comment: what happens is that when I make the screen smaller in height, the bottom overlaps with the top

Comment: @PotaOnasys That's the correct behavior. What's the behavior you are expecting?

Comment: I don't want the bottom to overlap the top when the screen height gets smaller

Comment: @PotaOnasys Where do you want that content to go? Is it that you want the menu content (the top content) to get a scrollbar when the window (and thus the menu div) get too small?

Comment: yes. I want a scroll bar shown. I don't want the bottom to ever overlap the top when the window height gets smaller.

Comment: @PotaOnasys Please see my [new answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34342040/2234742) that uses flexbox to allow a scrollbar and keep anything from being hidden.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative solution using flexbox instead of absolute positioning. In this case the top of the nav will scroll if there is too much content in it to fit.

**Live Demo:**

```css
.glb-nav {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.glb-nav-profile {
  background: red;
  height: 25px;
}
.glb-nav-social-icons {
  background: black;
  height: 50px;
}
.glb-nav-top {
  flex-grow: 1;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="glb-nav glb-nav-vertical glb-nav-left">
  <div class="glb-nav-top">
    <div class="glb-nav-logo">Example</div>
    Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />Example Text
    <br />
    <div class="glb-nav-left-arrow"></div>
    <div class="glb-nav-apps">
    </div>
    <div class="glb-nav-links">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>

    <div class="glb-nav-profile">
      <div class="glb-nav-profile-image">
        <img src="/images/Profile.svg" />
      </div>
      <div class="glb-nav-profile-name"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="glb-nav-social-icons">
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-tw"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-fb"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-in"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-lk"></div>
      <div class="glb-nav-social-icon glb-nav-pi"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/v8602cec/

Comment: If you change the height of the window, the bottom starts overlapping with the top

Comment: @PotaOnasys I'm not able to reproduce that. When I resize the height of the pane [on this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/v8602cec/), the excess text is correctly hidden behind a scroll bar.